# WPF Data binding with ResourceDictionary MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I'm trying to bind a View with a ViewModel within ResourceDictionary but it does not work.

The application is very simple window with 2 textboxes. When I type text to textbox1, atutomatically, textbox2 must get the same text. Of course my textboxes from the View have to be binded to my properties in ViewModel.

I'm new to WPF and the way I started to bind Views and ViewModels was in the codebehind of a View:

```
DataContext = new MyViewModel();
```

Now I'm trying to achieve a cleaner separation. My code is

App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="NavigationCleanBinding.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="/Views/MainWindowView.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="MainResourceDictionary.xaml" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

MainResourceDictionary.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xamlpresentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:NavigationCleanBinding.Views"
    xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:NavigationCleanBinding.ViewModels">

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:MainWindowViewModel}">
        <Views:MainWindowView />
    </DataTemplate>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

MainWindowView.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="NavigationCleanBinding.Views.MainWindowView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Grid>
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="61,14,0,0" 
             Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" 
             Text="{Binding TestData, Mode=TwoWay,
             UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <Label Content="Test:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0"
      Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="43" />
    <Label Content="Result:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,46,0,0"
      Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />

    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="61,48,0,0"
             Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" 

             Text="{Binding TestData, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindowViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace NavigationCleanBinding.ViewModels
{
    class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        private String _testData;
        public String TestData
        {
            get { return _testData; }
            set { _testData = value; }
        }

        private MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            _testData = null;
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

I changed property TestData to this:

```
public String TestData
    {
        get { return _testData; }
        set
        { 
            _testData = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TestData");

        }
    }
```

And implemened the INotifyPropertyChanged like this:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your Output window?

Comment: No errors, no warnings. It just does not work.

Comment: I don't think your DataContext is being set for your `MainWindowView`. I think, instead, `MainWindowViewModel` is the DataContext for `MainResourceDictionary`. Because you have your StartupURI set to MainWindowView, it'll create an instance of your Window, but never set the DataContext. I'm not positive, but I don't think your ResourceDictionary is doing anything at this point.

Comment: I have a similar idea about why it's not working but don't know how to make it work. I didn't find any example about how to do this trick yet.

Comment: Well, part of the problem is that I don't see anywhere in your code where you're creating an instance of your ViewModel. I'd recommend reading about MVVM-Light or Prism. They are MVVM frameworks that make it easy to setup WPF applications following the MVVM "pattern". Some of it can be pretty advanced (esp. with Prism), but in it's simplest form, is certainly doable for a beginner. Spend your time reading up a bit on the MVVM pattern before getting into those frameworks though, depending on how new you are to WPF/MVVM.

Comment: Well, at first I did the connection within the codebehind of the MainWindowView.xaml. There I had set DataContext=new MainWindowViewModel();

But I saw in a big project that there is no such thing. So, I'm confused. Of course, the project is far to big for me at this point to understand.

I'm 3 days old in MVVM :)

Comment: The big project could be using some sort of object creation framework (like Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF)) that is used in Prism v4. This is a framework that manages the creation of objects and their lifetime and introduces another term "dependency injection"(DI). All of these are advanced topics that you don't need to bother with atm. For the time being, I'd recommend you create the viewmodel in the codebehind and set it to the DataContext. It's not "bad" to do this in the code-behind, and it'll get you moving.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so user1064519 was on the right track:

- the View needs to be a `UserControl`, not a `Window`, as it is hosted in the MainWindow
- the ViewModel needs to be loaded into the MainWindow, this is what triggers the `DataTemplate` to be discovered and loaded.

  ```
  <Window x:Class="WpfTemplateBootstrap.MainWindow"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTemplateBootstrap"
      Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
      <ContentControl>
          <ContentControl.Content>
              <local:MainWindowViewModel />
          </ContentControl.Content>
      </ContentControl>
  ```

After that you should be up and running.
I have posted an in-depth example here: [wpf bootstrapping datatemplates--the chicken and the egg](http://www.thezenker.com/Blog/post/2013/01/03/wpf-bootstrapping-datatemplates-the-chicken-and-the-egg.aspx)

Comment: I think TheZenker respondend very well on his blog that is linked here.

Answer (score 1):

Your ViewModel must implement the interface [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and raise a `PropertyChanged` event when any bound property value changes, so that your view can know that changes occurred.

Comment: It still does not work... a friend of mine suggested to specify RelativeSource... somthing about ancestors... that I actually don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

DataTemplate sholudnt contain window, it can contains any kind of control.

**DataTemplate :**

```
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:MainWindowViewModel}">
        <Views:MainWindowView />
 </DataTemplate>
```

**UserControl :**

```
    <UserControl x:Class="NavigationCleanBinding.Views.MainView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="350" Width="525">

<Grid>
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="61,14,0,0" 
             Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" 
             Text="{Binding TestData, Mode=TwoWay,
             UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <Label Content="Test:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0"
      Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="43" />
    <Label Content="Result:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,46,0,0"
      Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />

    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="61,48,0,0"
             Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" 

             Text="{Binding TestData, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Window :**

```
 <Window x:Class="NavigationCleanBinding.Views.MainWindowView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<ContentControl Content={Binding}/>
</Window>
```

Comment: Actually it does not work... can you show me your app.xaml? And explain please how do main window binds to mai main view UserControl. Thanks!

Comment: How your UserControl got to know about DataTemplate? And if it is in some ResourceDictionary, UserControl should know about it, right?

Comment: You can place it in either resource dictionary or window.resources or app.resources, it depends on your needs